# Difference in usual contact structure on $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, contact-topology

I have seen the usual contact structure as either the kernel of $dz + xdy$ or the kernel of $dz - ydx$. They are contactomorphic, of course, just rotated.

However, **I was wondering if there are any particular reasons why one would use one form over the other as the ``standard''**? I had googled it to no avail. I did find that Etnyre states that "many authors prefer to use" the latter, but with no reasons named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically, contact transformations were introduced by S. Lie in the late nineteenth century in his attempts to get a general understanding of ordinary differential equations of order $1$, namely, problems having the following form $F(x,y,y')=0$. To do so, he introduced the notion of *line element* (which generalizes as *contact elements* for arbitrary smooth manifolds and lead to the study of contact geometry!), it consists of a point $(x,z)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and a nonvertical line $\ell$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ passing through it, such a line is of the form:
$$\mathrm{d}z-p\,\mathrm{d}x=0,$$
where $(x,z)$ is taken as the origin of $\mathbb{R}^2$, $(\mathrm{d}x,\mathrm{d}z)$ is the dual basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $p$ is the slope of $\ell$. The set of all line elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$, denoted by $C\mathbb{R}^2$, can be identified with $\mathbb{R}^3$ with coordinates $(x,z,p)$ and is naturally endowed with the globally defined contact form $\alpha_0\colon(x,z,p)\mapsto \mathrm{d}z-p\,\mathrm{d}x$. Using this setting, solutions to differential equations of order $1$, now, correspond to integral curves of the plane distribution $\ker(\alpha_0)$, in other word they are legendrian curves of $C\mathbb{R}^2$!

The theory can be developed further introducing $X_F$, the *Lie characteristic vector field* of $F(x,y,y')=0$, its integral curves are exactly the solutions of the given ODE, provided that $\alpha_0$ and $\mathrm{d}F$ are linearly independent along the level set $\{F=0\}$.

To wrap things up, I see mainly two reasons to have a preference for $\mathrm{d}z-p\mathrm{d}x$:

- It was the one historically studied and emerges in a very natural setting.
- It provides a self-contained and concise theory of differential equations of order $1$ and one may even argue that it contains in germs the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) for partial differential equations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know of any expository papers or books that contain more information on the history of contact geometry/topology? It doesn't seem to be well-contained in a book, but I did find a paper by Geiges I was looking to read through.

Comment: Sadly, I am not aware of any books or articles focusing on the development history of contact geometry, except the one you already mentioned by Geiges.

Comment: Thanks anyway! This is not the first contact geometry question you have answered of mine, so again, thanks. :)

Comment: It is my pleasure! :) Indeed, I remember, it was about an alternative definition of contact manifold! By the way, I do not find my answer convincing and I'm probably going to edit it out to add another explanation!

Comment: @anakhronizein Done, I basically did the computations in any dimension and add a little more information which can basically be useful when dealing with the equivalent definitions of a contact Hamiltonian vector field.